# how to get real address of urls in php switch statement

Tags: php, switch-statement

we have local PHP files A-Z. where redirection switch statement coded. Actually i want to request with id and get REAL address of redirection url. for example, domain1.com full path, domain2.com full path.

please somebody let me know, how to get REAL Domain path of these urls?

```
<?php

$id = $_GET['id'];

switch ( $id ) {

    case 01:
    header("Location: http://domain1.com");
    break;

    case 02:
    header("Location: http://domain2.com");
    break;


    default:
    header("Location: http://");
    break;

}

?>
```

**How i request by id?**

```
http://localhost/a.php?id=123
```

and its return Real Address of url like this:

```
http://www.domain.com/content/title.html // etc
```

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: did you know that `01` and `02` are octal numbers? now it's not a problem, but you may get unexpected results once you code `08` and `09`

Comment: yes, in second php file, i request numbers, and i want to get real path of urls, then i have code to insert real url in mysql database.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this?

```
$path = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$parts = parse_url('http://domain1.com');
echo $parts['host'];
```

output will we domain.com and if you need path use $parts['path']

Comment: please check my updated question, i want to request id and function return me real address